# Using Eloquent to build relationship that stretches across four or more tables

Tags: orm, laravel-4, relationship, eloquent

Here is a schema:

```
users: id

schools: id | district_id

school_users: id | school_id | user_id

districts: id
```

How would I build a relationship in Eloquent in order to return $district->users?

```
class District
{
    public function users()
    {
        //something that mirrors this functionality
        return $this->hasManyThroughThrough("User","SchoolUser","School");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should span accross 2 relationships:

```php
class District
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('School');
    }
}

class School
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}

class User
{
}

$books = District::with('schools.users')->get();
```